# Regex to find group of Regex inside a word

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I want to know how to generate a regex that detects all combinations of a regex inside a word. For example:

Matches for `"MAKE"` should return `"M", "MA", "MAK", "MAKE", "AKE", "AK", "A", "KE, "K", "E"`

So the regex for all these possible values is `[A-Za-z]+`

The problem is, how do I retrieve all the possible values from a single word:

```
Regex regex = new Regex( "[A-Za-z]+" );
foreach( Match m in regex.Matches( word ) )
{
    for( int i = 0; i < m.Groups.Count; i++ )
        Console.WriteLine( m.Groups[i].Value );
}
```

Is only retrieves me "MAKE" but I want to group all the matches inside this word.

Comment: You cannot make the regex engine match several times at one and the same place. It means you cannot solve this issue with a regex alone. Create all possible permutations of the string  without a regex.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew So my guess is to manually create the method to find all the possible substrings inside a word. I was just chilling trying to make the engine explode (:

Comment: Sorry, but regex is not meant to create such permutations. You might use nested capturing groups to capture values starting at the same point (like `((((M)A)K)E)`) but I doubt it is what you need.

Comment: Actually I managed to create an approach. It's possible but I haven't tested it so much nor calculated it's complexity :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I was trying to make an approach of a String substrings generator with Regex.
I had the idea but it was not so clear to me but I finally got an approach. Haven't tested it so much but by now it works and creates all possible substrings (From left to right) for an unknown word of variable size.

It works for C# Regex Engine. Haven't done benchmarking nor calculated complexity (Looks like O(N^2)? ).

I wanted to have a different approach for a problem I was given at a Microsoft Interview a couple of hours ago. The point was to find all possible words inside a matrix of N words of N size (In the example below, 4 words of size 4) in diagonal, horizontal and vertical (From left to right and Up to down).

```
    static void CheckWords( String[] words, HashSet<String> valid )
    {
        //Horizontal
        foreach( var w in words )
            FindWords( w, valid );

        //Vertical
        String word = "";
        for( int i = 0; i < words.Length; i++ )
        {
            for( int j = 0; j < words[i].Length; j++ )
                word += words[j][i];

            FindWords( word, valid );
            word = "";
        }

        //Diagonal
        String word2 = "";
        for( int i = 0, j = 0; i < words.Length; i++, j++ )
        {
            word += words[i][j];
            word2 += words[i][words[i].Length - i - 1];
        }

        FindWords( word, valid );
        FindWords( word2, valid );

    }

    static void FindWords( String word, HashSet<string> valid )
    {
        int len = word.Length;
        //Generate all possible (left to right) substring for String with Length - a [ FOr example, for "MAKE" we can have possible values for "MAKE", "MAK", "MA", "M", "AKE", "KE", "K, "E", "A
        for( int a = 0; a < len; a++ )
        {
            //Find all possible substring with this length { k = 1, k = 2, k = 3, ..., k = word.Length }
            for( int k = 1; k <= word.Length; k++ )
            {
                Match match = new Regex(@"([A-Za-z]{" + k + "}){1}").Match(word);
                //For all found groups, we just care for the first group wich contains the main unrepeated substrings
                for( int i = 0; i < match.Groups.Count - 1; i++ )
                    for( int j = 0; j < match.Groups[i].Captures.Count; j++ ) //Check each permutation for each word with K length. You can Console.Write each value to check it's generated string
                        if( valid.Contains( match.Groups[i].Captures[j].Value ) )
                            Console.WriteLine( match.Groups[i].Captures[j].Value );
            }
            word = word.Substring( 1, word.Length - 1 );
        }
    }
```

So given this input:

```
    HashSet<String> words = new HashSet<string>();
    words.Add( "MAKE" );
    words.Add( "MAD" );         
    words.Add( "END" ); 
    words.Add( "MINE" );                

    String[] array = { "MAKE", "IEMY", "NIAH", "ENDN" };

    CheckWords( array, words );
```

Should find all four words inside the array in the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

`((((M)(?=(((A)K)E))A)(?=((K)E))K)(?=(E))E)`

There is a programmatic way to construct a regex using a given word.
It's how I made this regex by hand.
I'll leave it as an exercise for you to deploy it.

```
 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 0 : len 4 ) 
MAKE  
 **  Grp 1 -  ( pos 0 : len 4 ) 
MAKE  
 **  Grp 2 -  ( pos 0 : len 3 ) 
MAK  
 **  Grp 3 -  ( pos 0 : len 2 ) 
MA  
 **  Grp 4 -  ( pos 0 : len 1 ) 
M  
 **  Grp 5 -  ( pos 1 : len 3 ) 
AKE  
 **  Grp 6 -  ( pos 1 : len 2 ) 
AK  
 **  Grp 7 -  ( pos 1 : len 1 ) 
A  
 **  Grp 8 -  ( pos 2 : len 2 ) 
KE  
 **  Grp 9 -  ( pos 2 : len 1 ) 
K  
 **  Grp 10 -  ( pos 3 : len 1 ) 
E
```

Formatted and the gory details:

```
 (                             # (1 start)
      (                             # (2 start)
           (                             # (3 start)
                ( M )                         # (4)
                (?=
                     (                             # (5 start)
                          (                             # (6 start)
                               ( A )                         # (7)
                               K
                          )                             # (6 end)
                          E
                     )                             # (5 end)
                )
                A
           )                             # (3 end)
           (?=
                (                             # (8 start)
                     ( K )                         # (9)
                     E
                )                             # (8 end)
           )
           K
      )                             # (2 end)
      (?=
           ( E )                         # (10)
      )
      E
 )                             # (1 end)
```

Comment: Thanks! Altough I want it to be done automatically for unknown String of unknow length. I Actually stayed doing tests and I finally got it:)

Answer (score 0):

If you only needed a regular expression to match all contiguous substrings of "MAKE", you could use the following:

```
^(M(|A(|K(|E)))|A(|K(|E))|K(|E)|E)$
```

alternatively, if you don't care about the start and end of the strings matching, you could shorten it to:

```
M(|A(|K(|E)))|A(|K(|E)|K(|E)|E
```